# what kind of url is this? please explain

Tags: adsense

/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=Organic&utm_campaign=remarketings&utm_term=health+care

The above code is placed after website name eg expample.com/page1/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=Organic&utm_campaign=remarketings&utm_term=health+care

what's the use of this, and please tell me how to get this type of AdSense ad code.

source:  view-source:https://nationalpost.info/china-is-importing-footballers-to-the-world-cup-in-qatar-in-2022/?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=Social&utm_campaign=remarketing&utm_term=business+related+top+articles

Answer (score 0):

The utm query parameters are used for tracking users and marketing campaigns. For example by using embedded adds or sending out newsletters. You will know, why users visit your page and what their reason is.

Comment: can you please explain what kind Adsense ad code website uses